# ¿Cómo calculo la distancia en kilómetros de una ruta de google maps dada la longitud y latitud?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, rutas

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que necesito saber qué distancia hay de un punto "A" a un punto "B" **no en línea recta**, necesito saber esa distancia pero con una ruta definida, no necesito mostrar el mapa, sólo mostraré el número de kilómetros de esa ruta.

El usuario ingresará dos direcciones, una de origen y otra de destino, las coordenadas las obtengo usando "Geocoder". Usé "Location" para saber la distancia entre dos puntos pero es en línea recta y no me sirve.

```
 distancia = puntoDestino.distanceTo(puntoOrigen) / 1000;
    txtKm.setText(String.valueOf(distancia));
```

Soy un novato en esto de usar las api de google, he buscado por la red para resolver mi problema, pero no encuentro una explicación que pueda usar en mi proyecto, muchas explicaciones tratan de dibujar la ruta pero yo no quiero eso, sólo necesito la información, no pondré el mapa de google maps.

Es mi primer publicación, si alguien puede guiarme o si hay alguna página que explique como resolver mi problema se los agradecería.

Comment: Hola para conseguir la distancia podes usar la api de google llamada `distance-matrix`, esta api te devolvera un array con distancias, tiempos y status. Cada elemento del array representa cada uno de los caminos que la api concidera adecuadas. te dejo la documentacion: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Comment: Hola, " la distancia entre dos puntos pero es en línea recta y no me sirve.". Recuerda que de un punto a otro puedes tener diferentes rutas, si tienes diferentes rutas ¿Cual de estas rutas determinaras para calcular la distancia en kilómetros?